# Could not autowire field Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: spring-mvc, autowired

May be the question Title seems to be duplicate but i'm getting the same error and couldnt find the answer in stackoverflow.

I have a controller

```
 @Controller
 public class MyController{

        @Autowired 
        BeanA beanA;

       @RequestMapping(value="/home")
        public String showHomeScreen(){
           return "home";
        }
    }
```

My BeanA class:

```
public class BeanA
{

    private Map<Object, Object> maps;

    //Setters,Getters
}
```

I've configure BeanA in spring config in this way

```
<bean id="beanA" class="com.mycompany.beans.BeanA">
 <property name="maps">
            <map>
                <entry key="Key 1" value="1" />
                <entry key="Key 2" value="2" />
           </map>
 </property>
</bean>
```

**updated:**

**Stacktrace:**

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.mycompany.beans.BeanA com.mycompany.controller.MyController.beanA ; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.mycompany.beans.BeanA] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
```

I also registered my context base package

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.*"/>
```

Now when i deploy my application i get the error as Could not autowire field "beanA"  Injection of autowired dependencies failed.

Can someone please help me to get out of this issue....

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, and you haven't provided the stack trace of the exception and the spring config file.

Comment: updated the stacktrace... Looks like it is trying to map BeanA class to mycontroller beanA... you could see in the stack trace it says com.mycompany.beans.BeanA to com.mycompany.controller.MyController.beanA

Comment: I could see the Bean com.mycompany.beans.BeanA is not registered.... from stacktrace : No qualifying bean of type [com.mycompany.beans.BeanA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right @Serge Ballesta. Bean A is not recognized by spring.
About Autowire its a typo i updated in the original post to Autowired

So i've added @component on BeanA and also changed context component scan in this way

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.*"/>
```

to

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany"/>
```

But still donno y my bean is not registered even though i mention in spring config xml.

Anywayz Now i'm not getting any errors, problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace says :

- controller `MyController` is correctly scanned by Spring but there are dependancies errors
- bean `BeanA` does not exist is same application context

Possible causes :

- the config file in which `beanA` is declared is not processed by Spring (most probable)
- there's a typo somewhere (it looks like there is none, but as you write `Autowire` without ending `d` ...)
- the context in which `beanA` is declared is neither same context as `MyController` one, nor a parent context